# Interval of convergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Interval of convergence of the series
  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n^2 x^n}{5^n \sqrt[5]{n}}$$is

a)$(-5,5].$
b)$[-5,5].$
c)$[-5,5).$
d)$(-5,5).$

My attempt:By using ratio test I got series converges if $|x|\lt5$.On $(-5,5) $series converges.Now I need to check at end points.
At $x=5$ series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n^2 }{  \sqrt[5]{n}}$ which is diverges and at $x=-5$ series become $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ n^2}{\sqrt[5]{n}}$.I am doubtful about convergence at end end points.please tell correct answer.

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of the two series at $x=5$ and $x=-5$? Does it approach $0$?

Comment: Use Cauchy- Hadamard. I think $(-5,5]$.

Comment: nth term of the series does not approach to zero

Comment: @ASHWINISANKHE: then you can conclude.

Comment: Yes Michel,your answer is correct.

Comment: Can you explain in detail?

Comment: @ASHWINISANKHE with what you have in the question, Michael's answer cannot be correct. The $n^{\text{th}}$ term in both cases is not approaching $0$, hence the series cannot be convergent in both cases. Unless you have a typo and you meant $\sqrt{n^5}$ in the denominator instead of $\sqrt[5]{n}$.

Comment: That means d is correct answer,is it?

Comment: @ASHWINI SANKHE I saw in the denominator $\sqrt{n^5}$.

Answer (score 1):

The general term of the resulting series when $\;x=\pm5\;$ is

$$\pm\frac{n^2}{\sqrt[5]n}=\pm n^{9/5}\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

and thus (d) is the correct choice, indeed.

Nevertheless, check carefully what Anurag tells you in his comment: if you *actually meant* $\;\sqrt{n^5}\;$ and **not** $\;\sqrt[5]n\;$ as you wrote, things are different.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your time.